# Python step debugger breaking upon introducing asyncio and httpx

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio, vscode-debugger, pdb

Python step debugger breaking upon introducing asyncio and httpx.

Developing Django application using vscode using this debug configuration

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
    
        {
            "name": "Python: Django",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/manage.py",
            "args": [
                "runserver"
            ],
            "django": true,
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

Nothing changed other than introducing this asynchronous module. I can also fix the debugger by removing import of httpx and asyncio.

A viable workaround for me would be any way to send a http request without awaiting the response, but using asyncio and httpx seems to be a common approach to do this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Are you sure you cannot be more precise than _"breaking"_? You know, error messages, descriptions of unexpected behavior, screenshots, etc.?

Comment: have you ever enabled step debugging while using asyncio and httpx?